# Is this RingBuffer thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, lock-free

I implemented the following data structure. However, I am not sure whether it is thread-safe. I am also looking for suggestions to improve it.

Right now the default std::memory_order_seq_cst is used everywhere since I wanna make sure it is correct first.

This is a First In First Out ring buffer, and four atomic integers are used.

> ```
> [------------------------------------------]
>
>   ^       ^       ^       ^
>   |       |       |       |    
> beg_sync_ beg_ end_sync_ end_
> ```

- [beg_sync_, beg_) in reading (in popping)
- [beg_, end_sync_) not touched
- [end_sync_, end_) in writing (in    pushing)

```
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <type_traits>
#include <shared_mutex>


template <class Mutex>
class SharedLockGuard {
 private:
  bool shared_lock_;
  Mutex& shared_mutex_;
 public:
  explicit SharedLockGuard(Mutex& shared_mutex, bool shared_lock = true)
  : shared_lock_(shared_lock), shared_mutex_(shared_mutex) {
    Lock();
  }

  void Flip() {
    Unlock();
    shared_lock_ = !shared_lock_;
    Lock();
  }

  ~SharedLockGuard() {
    Unlock();
  }
 private:
  void Lock() {
    if (shared_lock_) {
      shared_mutex_.lock_shared();
    } else {
      shared_mutex_.lock();
    }
  }

  void Unlock() {
    if (shared_lock_) {
      shared_mutex_.unlock_shared();
    } else {
      shared_mutex_.unlock();
    }
  }
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
class Ring {
 private:
  std::atomic<size_t> beg_;
  std::atomic<size_t> beg_sync_;
  std::atomic<size_t> end_;
  std::atomic<size_t> end_sync_;
  std::shared_mutex shared_mutex_;

  typename std::aligned_storage<
      sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type buffer_[N];

 public:
  Ring(): beg_(0), beg_sync_(0),
          end_(0), end_sync_(0) {}

  /**
   * \brief this function and only this function can increase beg_
   * \param data
   * \return false if it is empty
   */
  bool TryPopFront(T& data) {
    SharedLockGuard<std::shared_mutex> shared_lock_guard(shared_mutex_);

    if (beg_.load() == end_sync_.load()) {
      return false;
    }

    size_t beg = beg_.fetch_add(1);
    T* ptr = Access(beg % N);
    data = std::move(*ptr);
    ptr->~T();

    while (!beg_sync_.compare_exchange_weak(beg, beg + 1));

    return true;
  }

  /**
   * \brief
   * \param data
   * \return false if buffer is full.
   */
  template <typename ... ArgTypes>
  bool TryEmplaceBack(ArgTypes&& ... args) {
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, ArgTypes&& ...>::value,
                  "T must be nothrow constructable with Args&&...");
    SharedLockGuard<std::shared_mutex> shared_lg(shared_mutex_);

    if (beg_sync_.load() > ULONG_MAX / 2) {
      /// unlock shared, and lock exclusive
      shared_lg.Flip();

      size_t beg_sync_v = beg_sync_.load();
      size_t diff = beg_sync_v - beg_sync_v % N;
      beg_.fetch_sub(diff);
      end_.fetch_sub(diff);
      beg_sync_.fetch_sub(diff);
      end_sync_.fetch_sub(diff);

      /// unlock exclusive, and lock shared
      shared_lg.Flip();
    }

    if (end_.load() - beg_sync_.load() == N) {
      return false;
    }

    size_t end = end_.fetch_add(1);
    T* storage = Access(end);
    /// noexcept with static assertion
    new (storage) T(std::forward<ArgTypes ...>(args)...);

    while (!end_sync_.compare_exchange_weak(end, end + 1));

    return true;
  }

  void PopFront(T& data) {
    while (!TryPopFront(data)) {
      std::this_thread::yield();
    }
  }

  void PushBack(T data) {
    while (!TryEmplaceBack(std::move(data))) {
      std::this_thread::yield();
    }
  }

  template <typename ... ArgTypes>
  void EmplaceBack(ArgTypes&& ... args) {
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, ArgTypes&& ...>::value,
                  "T must be nothrow constructable with Args&&...");
    while (!TryEmplaceBack(args...)) {
      std::this_thread::yield();
    }
  }


 private:
  T* Access(size_t idx) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&buffer_[idx % N]);
  }

};
```

Comment: Honestly, I think it's a lot simpler if you created a non-thread safe data structure, and wrap that in a class that controls the access to the resource.  For example, if I gave you a `std::vector`, how would you make it thread-safe?  You can't fiddle around with the internals of vector, and vector is inherently not thread-safe.

Comment: Why are you using a mutex that guards access to atomic types? Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm sure this would be very valuable information to include as comments. In general, but even more with multithreading, adding comments that explain why you did something in a specific way (including assumptions and perhaps discarded approaches) is important. That said, one obvious downside is the busy-waiting. If, at some point, this is the right way, then it could be implemented outside of this class and also be documented appropriately.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you could subclass vector and override the methods to provide locking?

Comment: If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".